# Automate CSV File Creation Using Boto3 S3 and Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am doing a lab on the website LinuxAcademy.com The Course name is *Automating AWS with Lambda, Python, and Boto3*  and the specific lab I am having trouble with is *Lecture: Importing CSV Files into DynamoDB*.

In this lab we upload a .csv file into S3, an S3 event is generated in that specific bucket which then kicks off the Lambda script shown below:

```
import csv
import os
import tempfile

import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:
        source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            download_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, key)
            s3.download_file(source_bucket, key, download_path)
            items = read_csv(download_file)

            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for item in items:
                    batch.put_item(Item=item)


def read_csv(file):
    items=[]
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = {}
            data['Meta'] = {}
            data['Year'] = int(row['Year'])
            data['Title'] = row['Title'] or none
            data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            #data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            data['Meta']['Subject'] = row['Subject'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actor'] = row['Actor'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actress'] = row['Actress'] or None
            data['Meta']['Director'] = row['Director'] or None
            data['Meta']['Popularity'] = row['Popularity'] or None
            data['Meta']['Awards'] = row['Awards'] == 'Yes'
            data['Meta']['Image'] = row['Image'] or None
            data['Meta'] = {k: v for k,
                            v in data['Meta'].items() if v is not None}
```

The .csv file upload to s3 does invoke the lambda function.
I'm getting an error on line 20: `items = read_csv(download_file)`

Error from AWS CloudWatch:

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'download_file' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_handler
    items = read_csv(download_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s3.download_file(source_bucket, key, download_path)
items = read_csv(download_file)
```

The first line is calling the `download_file()` method on the Amazon S3 client to download a file to the local disk.

The second line is calling the `read_csv()` function, passing a variable called `download_file`. However, no variable called `download_file` has been defined, which is why you are receiving the error.

In looking at the code, the `read_csv()` function is expecting the name of a file to open. This appears to be available in the `download_path` variable, which contains the local directory and key. Therefore, change it to:

```
items = read_csv(download_path)
```

Comment: I have modified the code as suggested.  I am now getting a new error, which based on my research tends to make me think that the .csv file I am providing is not being parsed properly.                                                                                        The new error from CloudWatch:                                                    
[ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 26, in lambda_handler
    for item in items:

Comment: See: [Unable To Parse .csv in Python Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59460882/174777)