# Unable To Parse .csv in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am doing a lab on the website LinuxAcademy.com. The Course name is *Automating AWS with Lambda, Python, and Boto3* and the specific lab I am having trouble with is *Lecture: Importing CSV Files into DynamoDB*.

In this lab we upload a .csv file into S3, an S3 event is generated in a specified bucket which then kicks off the Lambda function shown below.  The function parses the .csv then uploads the contents into DynamoDB.

I was originally having issues with Line 23:

```
items = read_csv(download_file)
```

as Python was unable to define download_file. When changing to:

```
items = read_csv(download_path)
```

I was able to get past that error.

Now I am having an issue with Line 26:

```
for item in items:
```

The new error for #26 from CloudWatch is as follows:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 26, in lambda_handler
    for item in items:
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import os

import tempfile
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            download_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, key)
            s3.download_file(source_bucket, key, download_path)
            items = read_csv(download_path)

            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                **for item in items:**
                    batch.put_item(Item=item)


def read_csv(file):
    items=[]
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = {}
            data['Meta'] = {}
            data['Year'] = int(row['Year'])
            data['Title'] = row['Title'] or none
            data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            #data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            data['Meta']['Subject'] = row['Subject'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actor'] = row['Actor'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actress'] = row['Actress'] or None
            data['Meta']['Director'] = row['Director'] or None
            data['Meta']['Popularity'] = row['Popularity'] or None
            data['Meta']['Awards'] = row['Awards'] == 'Yes'
            data['Meta']['Image'] = row['Image'] or None
            data['Meta'] = {k: v for k,
                            v in data['Meta'].items() if v is not None}
```

I'm starting to think that this is related to the function not reading the .csv properly. The .csv is a small test file, contents below.

```
Year,Length,Title,Subject,Actor,Actress,Director,Popularity,Awards,Image
1990,111,Tie Me Up, Comedy,"Banderas, Antonio","April, Victoria","Al, Pedreo",68,No,NicholasCage.png
1991,112,Tie Me Up2, Comedy2,"Banderas, Antonio2","April, Victoria2","Al, Pedreo2",682,No2,NicholasCage2.png
1993,113,Tie Me Up3, Comedy3,"Banderas, Antonio3","April, Victoria3","Al, Pedreo3",683,No3,NicholasCage3.png
```

Comment: Is this your own code, or was it supplied to you?

Comment: Some useful advice here: https://blog.hartleybrody.com/debugging-code-beginner/

Comment: Code was supplied to me from LinuxAcademy course work.

Answer (score 0):

The `read_csv()` function does not contain a `return` statement.

Therefore this line:

```
items = read_csv(download_path)
```

does not assign any value to the `items` variable.

Therefore, it generates an error on this line:

```
for item in items:
```

Within the `read_csv()` function you probably want to add `data` to `items` after each row and then, at the end of the function, `return items`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas. Using that will give u a data frame which you can loop through easily. You can refer this link for pandas lib. - https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-read-csv